# Linker cannot find files despite them existing in a directory

Tags: c, macos, linker, clang, homebrew

I am trying to compile a simple program, but it is unable to link, resulting in undefined symbols. I am compiling on an ARM based Mac using the following command:

`clang datafinder.c -o datafinder -I/opt/homebrew/include -L/opt/homebrew/lib -v`

Here is my header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "/opt/homebrew/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "/opt/homebrew/include/libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "/opt/homebrew/include/libswscale/swscale.h"
```

I have tried directly specifying the location of the files in the cellar of homebrew in case it was an issue with clang being unable to process alias/shortcut files, but that doesn't seem to be the problem as it neither resolved the issue nor are there any problems with the include flag with how I am currently doing it (`-I/opt/homebrew/include`).

Currently I am only using the functions in `avformat.h` (I was trying to test the code before proceeding, but ran into this linking issue).

The linker states

```
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch arm64 -platform_version macos 14.0.0 14.2 -syslibroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -o datafinder -L/opt/homebrew/lib -L. -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/6.1.1_3/include -L/usr/local/lib /var/folders/5r/9g8w67kn4cbcbkt7452wfgr40000gn/T/datafinder-00169b.o -lSystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a

ld: Undefined symbols:
  _avformat_free_context, referenced from:
      _main in datafinder-775b1c.o
  _avformat_open_input, referenced from:
      _main in datafinder-775b1c.o
```

but in the directory I specified (`/opt/homebrew/lib`) these [image: aliases to these files] directly exist (not in any subdirectory or something)

Comment: Include files are not libraries, linker does not care about them

Comment: You don't appear to have requested the library providing those functions to be linked to the program.  Adding a folder to the library search path (via `-L`) is not sufficient.  You should add an appropriate `-l` option designating the specific library you need.